# In a @OneToMany relationship what order will the entities on the many side be fetched?

Tags: jpa, one-to-many

Let's say we have a @OneToMany relationship:

```
@Entity
pulic class MyEntity {
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<MyOtherEntity> myOtherEntityList;
}
```

When I load an instance of `MyEntity` from the data base, what will be the order of `MyOtherEntity` instances in the `List`? Can I specify what order I would like them to be in, for example, if I want them to be ordered by a specific field?

Comment: or @OrderColumn if wanting to preserve your order at persist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To order your list you can use two strategy

**first**

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@OrderBy("name ASC")
private List<MyOtherEntity> myOtherEntityList;
```

> Specifies the ordering of the elements of a collection valued
>   association or element collection at the point when the association or
>   collection is retrieved.

**second**

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@OrderColumn("order")
private List<MyOtherEntity> myOtherEntityList;
```

> Specifies a column that is used to maintain the persistent order of a
>   list

Remeber if you does not use above annotations your JPA provider performs a simple select and you lost any ordering.